# Most effective way to store more booleans

Tags: c, performance, memory-management

I need to store exactly four booleans in my struct in c. Yes I could use four integers or put them into an array but I would like to do it a bit nicer. I was thinking about an int like "0000" where each number would represent the boolean value, but then when editing I cant edit only the one digit, right? That doesnt look perfect either...

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Define "effective".  Do you mean fastest?  Smallest memory footprint?  Smallest code footprint?  Most elegant?

Comment: What is "most effective" for you? Using up less memory, being fast, easy use?

Comment: Sorry for not including that, I meant using less memory and easy to use

Comment: 4 bits is called a nibble, just to help you improve your Jargon with your chief programming officer :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use a bitfield struct:

```
struct foo {
  unsigned boolean1 : 1;
  unsigned boolean2 : 1;
  unsigned boolean3 : 1;
  unsigned boolean4 : 1;
};
```

You can then easily edit each boolean value separately, for example:

```
struct foo example;
example.boolean1 = 1;
example.boolean2 = 0;
```

Comment: Great, that looks perfect. Btw do I get it right that each one of those variables takes just one bit?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. However, most likely it will take up a little more because of memory padding. It is however certainly more memory-efficient than say using integers.

Comment: The four bits depicted will be padded to fill out an entire `unsigned`. In practice `unsigned char` can be used to hold up the bit fields, but if there are other members in the `struct` that might not affect the overall storage because the members are padded and aligned according to rules that generally make sense but can't be described in one sentence. Note also that fields of more than one bit can be described in the obvious way.

Comment: Btw I would have I more additional question. The value after colon (in this case its 1) defines a bit-length right? Is it possible to add default value as well? I need to set it to 1 on default instead of 0. Ive tried "unsigned boolean2 = 1 : 1;" and so unsuccessfully. Its not anything essential, but it would make my code more well-arranged.

Answer (score 2):

Using an int like "0000" is called using a bit field and is done quite regularly in practice. Yes, you can edit single values using [bit shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). Personally, I'd rather use an int to a bitfield struct as you can expand up to 32 values (if you're using a 32 bit int of course) without having to modify the struct.

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing millions of these, do it as packed bits.

If you need to access it millions of times per second, do it as ints (or shorts or chars).

If neither, then it doesn't matter.

If both, then you may have some serious performance tuning to do.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done using

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdbool.h

```
bool a = true;  // Could also be 'bool a = 1;'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct _eMyBool
{
    int m_iOne : 1;
    int m_iTwo : 1;
    int m_iThree : 1;
    int m_iFour : 1;
} eMyBool;
```

**However dont even think it is the most efficient way to use boolean.**

Because the additionnal assembly code generated so as to handle this has a price !

[For example read this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/11/26/9143050.aspx)

AFAI remember I think there should be a ratio of at least 7 for gained memory, because the footprint of the additionnal code for bitshifting when accessing the one-bit alignement member is really significant.

[This is the wikipedia article about data alignement.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Comment: The MSDN article is interesting, but in the OP's definition, "most effective" means "using less memory and easy to use". Here, the tradeoff is mostly a few more CPU instructions, not memory.

Comment: I tend to agree with you, but this price has to be kept in mind. Maybe it as not this article, but I clearly remember the ratio of 7. If I don't gain very much memory, then I consider the bitfield method a micro optmisation which "may" really have a price. And if the access to one of the boolean is a hugely repeated operation, appearing while profiling the application: No doubt I would remove the bitfield.